# Confusion about dimension of 1D CNN input

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to CNN and Keras so please forgive me if my question is very basic.

I have a 20k*150 matrix for the input of a binary classification. Each row of the data (each vector of 1*150) contains the information of a patient such as blood pressure, glucose, O2 saturation, etc, at a specific timestamp during the hospitalization. Each patient may have a different number of rows associated with them as the length-of-stay among patients is different.

I was recommended to apply a 1D CNN on this classification problem but I am very confused with identifying the inputs to the model.

Could you please help me to find the number of batches, steps, channels and number of outputs in the data that I have?

Comment: You say "Each patient may have a different number of rows associated with them as the length-of-stay among patients is different." Then i guessthe data would not be a 150 dim matrix ?

Comment: Can these rows be considered independent? In reality I know they aren't (as multiple rows belonging to the same patient). But for your modelling problem can these be considered independent? If not, you might wanna consider doing this as a time series problem.

Comment: @nav Each patient has multiple rows corresponding to different timestamps. But the number of features (columns) stays the same across all timestamps.

Comment: @thushv89 As you mentioned, they cannot be independent. May I ask how can I train the model as you said?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to predict. But I was suggesting using LSTM/GRU/CONVLSTM